# iPhoto Library Picker

Tags: photos.app, library

OK I have been upgrading and moving things around between computers for years and in that time I have managed to have a lot of duplicates in the iPhoto Picker:
[image]

I have consolidated the libraries down to three but the iPhoto Library Picker (hold OPTION when launching iPhoto) is filled with a bunch of old cruft that I would dearly love to remove. Problem is I can't find where this list is kept.

It does not seem to be in any of the iPhoto preferences in my home or system folder nor in Application Support either.

Any ideas where this data is stored?

Comment: Try to open each of them in your hard drive and check what information is here and what you need...

Comment: kirbrown, it's not the libraries, I am down to three, but all the duplicate names in the picker.

Answer (score 1):

Locate iPhoto in your *Applications* folder. <kbd>Control</kbd> + Click on the iPhoto application and "show package contents". The file you seek is there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain, but I suspect this is the relevant file:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iPhoto.plist
```

Look for the **RecentRootDirectories** key, and see if the entries it contains line up with what you're seeing in the UI.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I had trashed all the preferences files earlier. I also looked in the new preferences files with BBEdit and found nothing that pointed to a bunch of old libraries. Thanks anyway!